# Playing external video files with Actionscript 2

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

This is a basic script I'm using to play video files in Actionscript 2:

```
var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection();

nc.connect(null);

var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc);

obj_video.attachVideo(ns);

ns.play("vid.flv");
```

It works okay, but only for one specific video file strangely. It doesn't play any other video file, even videos of the same type/format. Can anyone shed some light on this issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

looks like as 3 to me. anyway, before you connect, add an event listener to detect when the connection is made. only them you do the rest. you should also add event listener before play, and on success, you attach the ns to the video.

Also add event listeners for errors and it should tell you if you have a typo, if the file itself is invalid, etc.

Comment: Actually, it is AS2, taken (nearly) directly from Adobe AS2 Reference. AS3 doesn't have a Video.attachVideo() method; it has Video.attachNetstream() instead.